# Mystery tbody tag being inserted

Tags: javascript, html

I have a custom component I'm working on and I borrowed code from one project verbatim from another.  Here's the trouble area:

```
<style>
    #history tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f2f2f2;}
</style>
<div class="ce-card" style="height:280px;overflow:auto;" id="myscroller">
    <table id="history" style="width:100%">
    </table>
</div>
```

Then later the table is appended to with this:

```
this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#history').innerHTML += `<tr><td>Term ${this._term}: ${text}</td></tr>`;
```

All of it works. However, I'm not getting my alternating highlighting because in project #2 the row is being wrapped with `<tbody></tbody>` tags. I have no use of tbody anywhere, but it crops up in just the new page I'm toying with. How do I suppress the insertion of `<tbody>` tags when setting innerHTML to have a `<tr>`?

I know someone will ask what happens when use `=` instead of `+=`. It's got the same problem.

Summary: `` xxx.innerHTML = `<tr><td>text</td></tr>` ``  produces different results in different projects. One of the two following:

```
<table><tr><td>text</td></tr></table>
<table><tbody><tr><td>text</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Edit:

According to what I'm reading in the comments, if I append multiple rows by appending HTML I should get the following:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBQEW.png

But there doesn't seem to be any way to *not* get it to bracket it with  ... except what appears to happen on another page (and apparently by accident).

This table was created identically: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kur1d.png Maybe the better question to ask is "how did I manage to do it the first time around? What did I set in CSS or something that's suppressing the insertion of a tbody?"

Comment: Are all tables in `shadowRoot` ? It's safe to assume that standard and expected behavior is out the window when you are in that environment.

Comment: In all cases, both working or not, they are in the shadowRoot.

Answer (score 2):

The browser *infers* the existence of a `<tbody>`. You cannot remove it.

A thing to keep in mind is that people have been writing broken HTML since the dawn of the web. Browser makers have chosen to handle that problem by making browsers do *more than* meet page authors halfway.

Try this experiment.

1. Create a bare HTML page like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>one</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

2. Open that page in your browser, and use Dev Tools to inspect it. You'll see a `<tbody>`.

---

**Q: Why do new `<tbody>` elements keep getting added?**

As stated earlier, the browser infers the existence of a `<tbody>`. But why?

<s>Because the DOM does not permit `<tr>` to be the direct descendant of `<table>`.</s>

A little to my surprise, [the DOM spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-table-element) *does* permit `<tr>` to be a direct descendant of `<table>`. Here's the exact text (emphasis mine):

> Content model:
>
> In this order: optionally a `caption` element, followed by zero or more `colgroup` elements, followed optionally by a `thead` element, followed by **either zero or more `tbody` elements or one or more `tr` elements**, followed optionally by a `tfoot` element, optionally intermixed with one or more script-supporting elements.

My read is that the spec permits this:

```html
<!-- Snippet 1: row wrapped in tbody -->
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr> <td> cell </td> </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Or this:

```html
<!-- Snippet 2: row as direct child of table -->
<table>
    <tr> <td> cell </td> </tr>
</table>
```

But *not* this:

```html
<!-- Snippet 3: mixed-case, table with both tbody and row children -->
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr> <td> cell </td> </tr>
    </tbody>
    
    <tr> <td> cell </td> </tr>
</table>
```

Since it's clear that modern browsers infer the existence of a `<tbody>`, Snippet #2 gets automatically transformed into Snippet #1. And that means any additional `<tr>` will be automatically wrapped in `<tbody>` in order to avoid Snippet #3.

I got the same results as you when I tried this in a bare HTML page with a table.

Comment: Yes, I see that. However, each tr is being wrapped in its own tbody. If I try to find the tbody that's inside the table, there is none to which I could append the row. Multiple appends get multiple tbody's.  And the stupid thing worked in a different context.

Comment: I still don't know why it's working in one place and not another, but a workaround is to insert my own tbody and append to that. I'd still like to know why I get a difference, though.

Comment: The reason you get an extra `<tbody>` is because your JS is appending a "bare" `<tr>` into `#history`, which is a `<table>`. Browsers will always insert a `<tbody>` between the parent `<table>` and a `<tr>`.

Comment: Tom, I'm still left with the mystery of why my other uses of this didn't have the problem of extra tbody. In fact, I got none at all. The solution, it seems to be, is to build your table with your own tbody tag and insert there. More or less, "doctor, it hurts when I do this." Then don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

It is normal behaviour for most browsers. It is inserted browser during processing your DOM. For more details refer to [official MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody). It is impossible to suppress `<tbody>`, maybe you can use it another way.
What about using in CSS `#history > tbody > tr:nth-child(even)` first collect all `tr` in one string IN JAVASCRIPT and then add it using `innerHTML` to `#history`

Comment: If it's impossible to suppress it, why is it suppressed in my original code?

Comment: Oh, also, the additional problem I have is that I get multiple tbody tags. so, with the tr enclosed in a tbody, the tr is always the first row.

Comment: Your problem is in adding each time one row using `innerHTML`. To deal with it first collect all `tr` in one string and then add it using `innerHTML` to `history`

Comment: That's the thing: if I had all the lines at once, I'd do exactly that. I don't.

Comment: It is not a problem. When you get a new row, refer to `innerHTML`, append it in JS with new `tr` and then add using `innerHTML`. Before appending remove `tbody` tags using `string.replace`

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer:**

As the intention here is to continuously add to the "history" table, the following should be more appropriate:

1. Start with a suitable markup (including a `<tbody>` element)
2. Use the DOM element method `.createElement()` to freshly create a new `<tr>`-element,
3. then fill in all the necessary `.innerHTML` into this `<tr>` before eventually
4. `.append()`-ing it to the `<tbody>`-target.

```js
const tbd=document.querySelector("#history tbody");

"abc".split("").forEach((v,i)=>appendEl(tbd,"tr",
`<td>Term ${i+1}:</td><td>${v}</td>`));

function appendEl(trgt,type,html){
 const el=document.createElement(type);
 el.innerHTML=html;
 trgt.append(el);
}

// And here is another "late" addition to the table:
appendEl(tbd,"tr",
`<td>last term:</td><td>"the end"</td>`);
```

```html
<table id="history"><tbody></tbody></table>
```

`appendEl()` is a little utility function that helps me do the above steps for each `<tr>`. jQuery has a built-in method `append()` that would be ideal for this job. Unfortunately there is no direct Vanilla JS equivalent method, but `appendEl()` kind of works in the same direction.

Doing it this way we avoid re-parsing the already existing table content. This should make the whole process faster and more stable (any previously attached event listeners or changed input values will be unaffected by it).

Comment: Generally if I have a collection to put in a table dynamically, I fill it all at once. If you can't tell from the table name, it's a history of activity. It grows as the page itself is done. I don't think I can adequately predict the future to fill the whole table at the start. :-D